# Won't let me sign in with gmail

Tags: pokemon-go

When I deleted and re-downloaded the game, it won't let me sign in with my gmail account and it won't give me the option to, it only says sign in with Pokemon trainers club

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to give it some time.

The Log-in options should disappear whenever the servers are offline due to issues or maintenance. Unfortunately, sometimes you'll have one but not the other log-in button appear even if it's not working for anyone.

The following 3rd-Party site has been pretty good in giving a glimpse if the servers are still down: http://www.mmoserverstatus.com/pokemon_go